# Can I use multiple JMS listeners in one Component?

Tags: java, spring, jms

I have a component with multiple listeners in one component:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic.stomp}")
public void receiveMessage(final TextMessage msg) throws Exception {
    printMessage(msg);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic.mqtt}")
public void receiveMessage(final BytesMessage msg) throws Exception {
    printMessage(msg);
}

@JmsListener(destination = "${jsa.activemq.topic.mqtt.alert}")
public void receiveAlertMessage(final BytesMessage msg) throws Exception {
    printMessage(msg);
}
```

The first listener (topic.stomp) reads all messages perfectly. Other two don't get messages even if I leave just one.

Comment: The fact that the `topic.mqtt` and `topic.mqtt.alert` listeners don't get messages even if they are the only ones indicates to me that the problem is with the listener itself rather than the fact that there are multiple listeners.